# Как ночью выполнять одну функцию, а днём — другую?

Tags: javascript, время

Есть код:

```
var startScript = (new Date().getHours()+1)%24;//Берем текущий час например 21 прибавляем 1, 21 + 1 = 22 это час когда нужно запустить скрипт
if(new Date().getHours() >= 22)//Если мы зашли на сайт и минуты равны 0, например 22:00 то сразу же запускаем наш скрипт
    myScript();
loop();//Вызываем наш цикл
function loop(){
    var date = new Date();//Берем текущее время
    if(date.getMinutes() == 0 && date.getHours()==startScript){//Если минут равны нулю и текущий час тому в котором нужно запустить скрипт
          // startScript = (startScript+1)%24 ;//прибавляем +1 к часу в котором нужно запустить скрипт
            myScript();// и запускаем скрипт
    }
    setTimeout(loop,500);//проверка текущего времени 1 раз в 30 секунд, если нужно чтобы скрипт запускался с точностью до секунды (22:00:00) поставить ~500
}

function myScript(){
    link.href = 'assets/css/dark.css'; // включаем темную тему
    localStorage.setItem('themeStyle', 'dark'); // записываем значение в localStorage
}

function myScript2(){
    link.href = 'assets/css/light.css'; // включаем светлую тему
    localStorage.setItem('themeStyle', 'light'); // записываем значение в localStorage
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы допустим функция `myScript` запускалась с `22-00` и действовала до `07-00`, а после `07-01` запускалась `myScript2` и действовала до `21-59`?

Comment: Надо чтобы при вызове определенной функции в одно время суток вызывалась одна функция, а в другое - вторая? Или надо планировщик задач составить для браузера? Cron на js?

Comment: Первое, чтобы при вызове определенной функции в одно время суток вызывалась одна функция, а в другое - вторая

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С 22:00 до 6:59 включительно.
С 7:00 до 21:59 включительно.

```js
setInterval(detectTime, 1000);    

function detectTime(){
 let h = (new Date()).getHours();
 if(h >= 22 || h < 7) myScript();
  else myScript2();
}

function myScript(){
 console.log('Night');
}

function myScript2(){
 console.log('Day');
}
```